# How to find a word and only this word?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Here's my script :

```
word_list = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4']

word_list1 = ['word5']


classe = []

for i in range(0, df.shape[0]) :
    #classebis = ['']

    classe.append('')
    
    
    
    for item in word_list:
        if item.lower() in df["Description"][i].lower():        
            if classe[i] != ('') and classe[i] != ('Classe1'):
                classe[i] = classe[i]  + ' \ ' +  'Classe1'
            else:
                classe[i] = 'Classe1'

         
      
            
    for item in word_list1:
        if item.lower() in df["Description"][i].lower():           
            if classe[i] != ('') and classe[i] != ('Classe2'):
                classe[i] = classe[i]  + ' \ ' +  'Classe2'
            else:
                classe[i] = 'Classe2'
```

My question is simple, how to tell the script to find the word `word5` in `Description` but the whole word `word5` because here if there is the word `word5555`, my script will affect `Classe2` and that's not what I want.

Comment: It's not clear what you need. Try to make a reproducible example and desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use regex, example:

```
import re

# Example 1: word5
example_string = 'word5 word5555'
only_word5 = re.findall(r'word5\b', example_string)
print(only_word5)
```

Comment: How to incorporate this to my loop ?

Comment: if you really want to stay with your loop go ahead with this one: df["Description"][i].str.findall(r'word5\b'')